# How can IPAddressField error message be changed

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using:

```
djangorestframework==3.11.0
django==3.0.3
```

I have changed the `CharField` `Error_message` easily, but when I try to change the error message for the `IPAddressField`:

```
class InterfaceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ip_address = serializers.IPAddressField(protocol="IPv4",
                                        required=False,
                                        allow_blank=True,
                                        error_messages={'invalid': 'test fail'},
                                        )
```

The result is always:

```
{"error_message": {
"ip_address": [
  "Enter a valid IPv4 address."
]}}
```

And the response is:

> 2020-03-18 13:13:12,878 : ERROR : response : {'error_message':
>   {'ip_address': [ErrorDetail(string='Enter a valid IPv4 address.',
>   code='invalid')]}}

Comment: What input are you using as `ip_address` to test this?

Comment: @AKS Im using "string"

Answer (score 1):

As you can see that the error message is very specific:

```
'Enter a valid IPv4 address.'
```

While looking at the code, I couldn't find such an error message in DRF. It meant that the message is coming from django validator and particularly [`validate_ipv4_address`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.3/django/core/validators.py#L256).

As you mentioned that you are using `"string"` as input to test it. If you look at the [`to_internal_value`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.11.0/rest_framework/fields.py#L944) of the `IPAddressField`, you will notice that the value `"string"` won't raise any errors there. From there, it goes to validators and produces the message that you see.

Because, `validator` is directly raising the `ValidationError`, it doesn't go through the `fail` method of the serializer. And, hence it is not able to lookup the `invalid` key in the error messages that was provided in field.

Comment: so I cant use "error_messages", the only way is to override the validator ?

Comment: No, I don't see a way to use `error_messages`  here. Also, there is no way to override the existing validator. The only thing you can do is extend the validators. The validators which will be passed to the field will appear first in the list so may be that way you can have a custom message. But the question remains that exactly what are you going to check as part of the validator and are you just going to use the existing django validator and wrap it in your own somehow.

Comment: maybe this is a bug, is it supposed to work like this ?

Comment: I think it is like this because the IP address validators in django are not built in a way where they can accept custom messages like how it is done in `MaxLengthValidator`  because they don't extend from `BaseValidator`. If you want to test whether the error messages you passed are really working or not, you can try sending an integer value and this will trigger the custom error message.